# What the difference between ga:keyword (UA) and sessionGoogleAdsKeyword (GA4) dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics-api

What the difference between ga:keyword (UA) and sessionGoogleAdsKeyword (GA4) dimensions ? Should i expect difference if I compare total of those dimensions ?

Not indicated as equivalent by Google but it look the same, I found very few informations about it on internet.